# R: code analysis tools

Tags: performance, r, analysis

Are there any tools in R that would allow me to see what is slowing down a function ( lines of code in the function that takes most amount of time , statistics etc.) ?

Cheers !

Comment: [Rprof](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/Rprof.html)

Comment: or [profr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profr/index.html) if that's more appealing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple guide on Rprof, http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Profiling-R-code-for-speed

And of course the package description: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/Rprof.html